# Unexpected Behaviour in Component Rendering in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I'm running my application on local and when I'm on the Login page , it calls all the jsx components before even mounting those. Is this common behaviour or there is a way to avoid this so that it doesn't affect performance of the application.

[image]

Edited:

```
          <div className={`bg-[#F8FCFE] relative`}>
            {showNav ? (
              <div className="border fixed top-0 right-0 w-full 
             !z-50">
                <Navbar />
              </div>
            ) : (
              ""
            )}
            <div className="mt-[5%] min-h-[85vh] ">
              <Routes>
                {/* <Route path="/" element={ <PackageBuilder 
           pageState ={pageState} handleBack = {handleBack} 
           handleNext = 
             {handleNext}/> } /> */}
                <Route path="/" element={<Login />} />
                <Route element={<RequireAuth allowedRole="admin" 
               />}>
                  <Route path="/profile" element={<Settings />} />
                  <Route path="/packageconfig" element=. 
              {<PackageConfig />} />
                </Route>
                <Route path="/leads" element={<Leads />} />
                <Route path="/packagebuilder" element=. 
           {<PackageBuilder />} />
                <Route path="/packages" element={<Packages />} />

                <Route path="*" element={<Error />} />
              </Routes>
            </div>

            {reportPopup && <ReportAside />}

            {showNav ? <Footer /> : ""}
          </div>
```

So this is the App component. When the login component renders, every children of the components present in App components is called like shown in the image i.e a screenshot from Network details. So does this mean its rendering all the components in the application even when its still on the login page and does this affect the performance of the application.

Comment: Please provide reproducible code of your problem. With image it will not help.

Comment: Provide some code or create stackblitz URL.

Comment: I have edit the post with the App component of my application